# Which method is easier to implement and analyse about the security and privacy issues in Internet of Things? Hardware implementation or Simulation.?

Tags: security, iot, privacy

If Simulation is best then which tool is relevant to do.?
Can anyone suggest me how to analyse the security and privacy level of an application in IoT.?
Also can anyone suggest a best tool to test algorithms for Security and Privacy in IoT.?

Answer (score 0):

This is really off topic for SO, but in general terms, a simulation will be better for analysis because you can get far more insight into the runtime environment than you do in hardware, and you don't need the analysis in a shipping product, only during development. If you're doing heavy encryption in this device, being able to see what's it's up to in shipping hardware would constitute a security hole.

You're also very vague on what it is you're testing. If you can see exactly what data is being captured and how it is being sent (and where), that's all you need to know; how it's implemented internally doesn't matter.